# Python graph visualization and editing with PyQt

Tags: python, graph, pyqt, graphviz

I want to expose some kind of graph explorer widget in Python using PyQt and some library.  Does such a library exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Graph) could be a good solution for you.  According to its web page it doesn't seem to depend on anything that would keep it from working with PyQt.

Another possibility, though messier, would be to incorporate whatever [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) does to draw graphs.

Comment: It took some digging (the NodeBox website is not very upfront about it), but looking at the source code it does appear to be Mac OS X only.  Was not aware of that when I suggested it.  However, it's open source and much of the functionality seems to exist in Python code, so it is probably possible to use in other environments.  It seems that the author is only focused on Mac OS X, though, so that's all that's available now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the nodebox-gl fork version of nodebox that support unix, but I can't find the fork version graph in nodebox :(

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[nodebox-opengl](https://github.com/nodebox/nodebox-opengl) has a [graph module](https://github.com/nodebox/nodebox-opengl/blob/master/examples/08-physics/07-graph.py). Quite nice I must say, I don't know how it will interact with PyQt though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late, check out http://code.google.com/p/yapgvb/